# Check if entity is loaded using AsNoTracking

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Is there a way to check if the entity was loaded using **AsNoTracking()** or not?

As you know, the following code will **not** work for entity loaded using **AsNoTracking()**.

```
ef.Entry(db).Collection(p => p.tblProducts).Load();
ef.Entry(db).Collection(p => p.tblOrders).Load();
...
...
...
```

Therefore, if the entity "**db**" was loaded using **AsNoTracking()** then I will do the following for loading its children.

```
db.tblProducts = ef.tblProducts.AsNoTracking().Where(x => x.WarehouseId == db.WarehouseId).ToList();
db.tblOrders = ef.tblOrders.AsNoTracking().Where(x => x.WarehouseId == db.WarehouseId).ToList();
...
...
...
```

I know it may not be a good approach, but if entity "**db**" was loaded using **AsNoTracking()**, then I know that its children do not need to be tracked too.

The question is, how to find out if the entity (that passed in the function) was loaded using **AsNoTracking()** or not.

**POSSIBLE SOLUTION**

I found this post here [EntityFramework Code First - Check if Entity is attached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10027493/entityframework-code-first-check-if-entity-is-attached), someone post the answer like this

```
public bool Exists<T>(T entity) where T : class
{
    return this.Set<T>().Local.Any(e => e == entity);
}
```

So, can I use

```
if (Exists(db))
{
    ef.Entry(db).Collection(p => p.tblProducts).Load();
    ef.Entry(db).Collection(p => p.tblOrders).Load();
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
else
{
    db.tblProducts = ef.tblProducts.AsNoTracking().Where(x => x.WarehouseId == db.WarehouseId).ToList();
    db.tblOrders = ef.tblOrders.AsNoTracking().Where(x => x.WarehouseId == db.WarehouseId).ToList();
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

What do you think?

Thanks!

Comment: I think it is good approach and you can use it

Comment: @AdilMammadov thanks mate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to this post [EntityFramework Code First - Check if Entity is attached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10027493/entityframework-code-first-check-if-entity-is-attached), I create a DbContext extension (as suggested on the link).

```
public static bool Exists<TEntity>(this DbContext ctx, TEntity entity)
    where TEntity : class
{
    return ctx.Set<TEntity>().Local.Any(e => e == entity);
}
```

And it worked nicely!

```
if (ef.Exists(db))
{
    ef.Entry(db).Collection(p => p.tblProducts).Load();
    ef.Entry(db).Collection(p => p.tblOrders).Load();
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
else
{
    db.tblProducts = ef.tblProducts.AsNoTracking().Where(x => x.WarehouseId == db.WarehouseId).ToList();
    db.tblOrders = ef.tblOrders.AsNoTracking().Where(x => x.WarehouseId == db.WarehouseId).ToList();
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

I hope this post could help someone with similar problem.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for sharing.