# Updating an entity with a navigation property is trying to insert new row for property entity Entity Framework Core 2

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have an entity (`Entity1`) which has a property of another entity (`Entity2`). The database is set up correctly and when I insert a new row for `Entity1`, the foreign key value is correct and I can insert infinite number of rows for `Entity1` and they all reference `Entity2` correctly.

However, when I make a change to `Entity1`, call `Attach()` and then try to save those changes, I'm getting a SQL exception that says it can't insert a new row for `Entity2` because `IDENTITY_INSERT` is not on.

I obviously don't want to do anything with `Entity2` - definitely not insert a new row, I just want to update values in the `Entity1` table.

I am using an adapter pattern to adapt everything from my business models to my data entities and everything there looks fine.

I'm happy to supply code if you think that would help, but right now I'm just looking for some high level ideas of where to start chasing this one down.

TIA

Comment: Some code samples would be really helpful - there's any number of things this could be. It sounds most to me like you're adding a version of Entity2 that is not being tracked by the saving context, but it's very difficult to help with why without code unfortunately

Comment: I think you might be on to something.  I'll play around with this idea and if I can't sort it out, I'll post some code as a follow-up.

Comment: @NickMurphy Is there a way in VS debugger to see if entities are already attached and being tracked?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12573886/8563429 will work in the watch window. Alternatively in you can expand your context object, expand the Entity2 set, and evaluate Local by allowing all threads to run. Anything in there is being tracked

Comment: @NickMurphy well I had a few issues in play here but I got it all sorted out now.  Thanks so much for putting me on the right path - I had a disconnected entity at first (you were right) and then my adpater was creating a new instance of Entity2 and so I was getting "another entity with same key...." problems.  Thanks again.