# How to know if an object is tracked by Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm using .NET 6 and Entity Framework Core 6 (6.0.2) in an ASP.NET Core Web API project.

Assuming I have:

```cs
public class MyModel 
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string MyData { get; set; }
    //etc...
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<MyModel> MyModels { get; set; }

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> opt) : base(opt)
    {
    }
}
```

If I'm in a generic function with the object `MyModel myModel`, then how can I know if this instance of `MyModel` is an entity tracked by Entity Framework Core?

I'm looking for a function like:

```cs
ApplicationDbContext context = ...
MyModel myModel = ...
//ecc...
bool result = context.IsOneOfMyEntity(myModel);
```

Comment: Do you want to know if the *type* is part of the entity model, or if the *instance* is being tracked by the current context?

Comment: I mean instance, I'will edit the question to correct it.

Comment: Well, then you can simply check if it's attached: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10027493/861716

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [Entry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.entry?view=efcore-6.0) method

> This method may be called on an entity that is not tracked. You can then set the State property on the returned entry to have the context begin tracking the entity in the specified state.

and check the [`State`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.entityentry.state?view=efcore-6.0) property for value other than [`Detached`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entitystate?view=efcore-6.0)

> Detached   0   The entity is not being tracked by the context.

e.g.

```cs
bool tracked = context.Entry(myModel).State != EntityState.Detached;
```