# Referencing same Entity with different names in an Entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a model like:

```
public class Sample
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid SampleId { get; set; }

    public virtual SampleProperty Saloon { get; set; }
    public virtual SampleProperty Room { get; set; }
    public virtual SampleProperty Balcony { get; set; }
}
```

and a related entity:

```
public class SampleProperty
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Piece Piece { get; set; }
    public FloorType Floor { get; set; }
    public WallType Wall { get; set; }
    public DoorType Door { get; set; }
    public WindowType Window { get; set; }
}
```

and ofcourse related Enums for the types in SampleProperty Entity.

Related controller is:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Sample(Sample model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(model.Saloon).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.Entry(model.Room).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.Entry(model.Balcony).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

Controller during get operation is:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Sample(Guid? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Sample @sample = db.Samples.Where(x => x.SampleId == id).FirstOrDefault();
        if (@sample == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        @sample.Room = new SampleProperties();
        @sample.Saloon = new SampleProperties();
        @sample.Balcony = new SampleProperties();

        return View(@sample);
    }
```

By the way; I am including following properties in View;

```
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Saloon.Id)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Room.Id)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Balcony.Id)
```

My problem is: When I try to update this entity. I am having error below. Do you have any idea?

> Attaching an entity of type
>   'Project.Models.SampleProperties' failed because another
>   entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This
>   can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an
>   entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have
>   conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and
>   have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use
>   the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and
>   then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as
>   appropriate.

Comment: Do you in any way prevent that two (or three) of the `SampleProperty` references are set to the same object? If not, that would be a source of possible exceptions because you can attach the same key twice. Anyhow, I think you better convert this into a 1:n association.

Comment: I didn't want to create separate objects having same attributes. But of course that can be an option if can't find a solution. Thank you!

Comment: You might have a look at my answer on [ASP.NET MVC - Attaching an entity of type 'MODELNAME' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23201907/asp-net-mvc-attaching-an-entity-of-type-modelname-failed-because-another-ent/39557606#39557606).

Comment: You might have a look at my answer on [ASP.NET MVC - Attaching an entity of type 'MODELNAME' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23201907/asp-net-mvc-attaching-an-entity-of-type-modelname-failed-because-another-ent/39557606#39557606).

Answer (score 1):

In my case this exception was fired because I was Attaching the same Entity (class) with the same Pk twice. E.g.:

```
db.Users.Attach(dbRecord.CreatorUser);
db.Users.Attach(dbRecord.OwnerUser); //<- If CreatorUser== OwnerUser then ERROR
```

You can avoid this using a simple comparison:

```
db.Users.Attach(dbRecord.CreatorUser);
if (dbRecord.CreatorUser.Pk != dbRecord.OwnerUser.Pk)
{
    db.Cabinets.Attach(dbRecord.OwnerUser);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Attaching an entity of type 'Project.Models.SampleProperties' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value.` it appears you are attaching an entity.

You haven't displayed the code that is attaching the entity (which would be helpful).  However, most likely the entity is already attached/materialized from the database to the context somehow.  So what you are looking for is a [the most reasonable way to find out if an entity is attached to the dbcontext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6033390/what-is-the-most-reasonable-way-to-find-out-if-entity-is-attached-to-dbcontext-o/6037277#6037277).

There is also the chance that you haven't attached ([DbSet.Attach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.attach%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)) the model back to the DbContext.

*Update*

I think your code should look like:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Sample(Sample model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Added Line
            db.Samples.Attach(model);

            db.Entry(model.Saloon).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.Entry(model.Room).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.Entry(model.Balcony).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: I think you are right and I made a mistake there by declaring them as new but I really don't know what is the proper way. So I made the revision on the question and added the missing part that you requested.

Comment: Updated per your comment.

Comment: sorry for my late reply but it didn't. I think it is better to move with separate entities for each type

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it is not the answer for my question but I couldn't find a proper solution rather than assigning all the entities as seperate objects in the same entity like:

```
public class Sample
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid SampleId { get; set; }

    public Piece SaloonPiece { get; set; }
    public FloorType SaloonFloor { get; set; }
    public WallType SaloonWall { get; set; }
    public DoorType SaloonDoor { get; set; }
    public WindowType SaloonWindow { get; set; }
    public Piece RoomPiece { get; set; }
    public FloorType RoomFloor { get; set; }
    public WallType RoomWall { get; set; }
    public DoorType RoomDoor { get; set; }
    public WindowType RoomWindow { get; set; }
    public Piece BalconyPiece { get; set; }
    public FloorType BalconyFloor { get; set; }
    public WallType BalconyWall { get; set; }
    public DoorType BalconyDoor { get; set; }
    public WindowType BalconyWindow { get; set; }
}
```

I know, it is not charming...