# How to delete an entity when its properties reference same entity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have models similar to this:

```
public class Line
{
    public int Id {get; set;}   
    public int FromStopId {get; set;}
    public int ToStopId {get; set;}
    public virtual Stop FromStop {get; set;}    
    public virtual Stop ToStop {get; set;}    
}

public class Stop
{
    public int Id {get; set;}   
    public int OwnerId {get; set;}
    public virtual Owner Owner {get; set;}    
}
```

`Lines` have different `Stops`, however many `Stops` can have the same `Owner`.

I load a complete `Line` entity using `Include` as follows:

```
public virtual IQueryable<T> Get(int id, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] include)
{
    if (include.Any())
    {
        var set = include.Aggregate<Expression<Func<T, object>>, IQueryable<T>>
                            (dbSet, (current, expression) => current.Include(expression));
    }

    return dbSet.AsNoTracking<T>().Where(x => x.Id == id);
}
```

Using the above I can load a `Line` entity, its `Stops` entities and their `Owners`, which in this case is the same.

Now, when I try to delete the `Line` entity I do:

```
dbSet.Attach(entity);
dbSet.Remove(entity);
```

However, I get the exception:

> Attaching an entity of type 'Owner' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate.

I am assuming that this is caused because both `Stops` have the same `Owner`. However, the `Owner` is not the same entity but 2 entities which are created independently for every `Stop` when loading the `Line`.

How can I delete `Line` entity in such a case?

Comment: Check if this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30350058/attaching-an-entity-of-type-x-failed-because-another-entity-of-the-same-type) helps. If entity is loaded from context then don't attach it.

Comment: @Sarang The entity is detached because I use `AsNoTracking()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to delete an entity you can

1)create a new object
2)set its Id property
3)Attach it
4)Delete it

Something like:

```
var toDelete= new MyEntity{ Id = 123 };
context.MyEntities.Attach(toDelete);
context.MyEntities.Remove(toDelete);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Deleting a record only requires the Id to be set,this way will probably bypass your problem

Comment: I was going to skip EF and use `IDbConnection` and `IDbTransaction` for deletes but this workaround works just as well.